# UITable View Cell not Appearing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I added a table view to a normal view controller and inside that table view I made a prototype cell. Ive done some work to make the cell appear but it won't. How do I fix this? Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class NewsScreenViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var trendingButton: UITabBarItem!
@IBOutlet weak var newestButton: UITabBarItem!
@IBOutlet weak var topJournalists: UITabBarItem!
@IBOutlet weak var tabBar: UITabBar!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return UITableViewCell()

    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}


}
```

Comment: did you connect all outlets from storyboard? and did you set the cell identifier from the storyboard?

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has `return UITableViewCell()` as its first line - it won't dequeue your cell, its just returning a new `UITableViewCell`

Comment: @ksa_coderyes and yes

Comment: @mittens what should i change it to?

Comment: add `return cell` after you dequeue your reusable cell with your specified identifier at the end of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: @mittens so replace return UITableViewCell() with return cell?

Comment: return the cell after you dequeue it from your table view```var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell; 

return cell
```

Comment: So I tried this and it didn't work is this what you meant?

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
        
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell
        
        return cell
    }

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return cell` after you get the cell and give it something to display. Try something more like this

```
let fillTableViewArray = [String]()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReuseableCellWithIdentifier("cell")

//now that you have that cell you have to put something into it. For example an Array of strings, can be used to fill the table view
cell!.textLabel?.text = fillTableViewArray[indexPath.row]

return cell!

}
```

If you want to do this in the storyboard, you can instead add a label to the prototype cell in the storyboard, set an integer value for the label's tag, and then find the label by adding these two lines after you do `let cell = ...`

```
let label = cell.viewWithTag(100) as UILabel!
label.text = fillTableViewArray[indexPath.row]
```

I hope this helps fix your issue

Comment: Just tried that and got this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: on which line? where are your optionals?

Comment: label.text = fillTableViewArray[indexPath.row]

Comment: Does the cell identifier in your storyboard match EXACTLY the string that your are passing as the argument in your code? Ok, if you are using that, then did you add a label in the storyboard, into the prototype cell? and then give it a tag?

Comment: you mean the reuse identifier?

Comment: yeah it looks the same

Comment: And did you create an array named `fillTableViewArray`? and did you put any values in it?

Comment: well make sure it is exaclty the same. copy paste it from on to the other. Then you just  use the code from the first part of my example, just to simplify things and narrow down the culprit of your problem. You can use a label later but for now lets just get the cell's text label programmatically

Comment: There only needs to be 3 lines inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. 1) `let cell =...`   2) `cell.textLabel.text = ...` 3) `return cell`  ... as long as your `fillTableViewArray` has valid values in it (just make it an array of Strings for simplicity sake right now) then this code will work.

Comment: Here it is: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        var fillTableViewArray = [String]()
        fillTableViewArray = ["Test"]
        
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell
        
        let label = cell.viewWithTag(100) as! UILabel!
        label.text = fillTableViewArray[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }

Comment: You need to use ` `  <--- those, in order to put code into comments. If you have a mac then you can find them right under the escape key. What you've written above is very hard to read. However, take the Array and move it to the instance level for now, toward the top of your class. Just give it a few values like `let fillTableViewArray = ["one", "two", "three"]`

Comment: I also just made a few minor edits to the my example code that you should take note of

Comment: Ok i got "One" to show up now how do i get my prototype cell to pop up?

Comment: That was the text label of your prototype cell. You can set other properties of it, read apple's documentation on table view and table view cells. To increase the number of cells that return, if you haven't figured it out by now, in the `numberOfRowsInSection` func, you return any number of rows you want, and cells will be recycled to as the table view is scrolled. For example, `return fillTableViewArrat.count` will make exactly as many rows as there are elements in the array.

Comment: If you have more questions you should probably take some time to figure out as much as you can and then post a new question if you need to, as this one has been answered.